# SQL Server INSERT Performance (SQL, Azure SQL Database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have two tables, first one 'A' contains approximately 400k rows and table 'B' - 12k rows. I need to select ~350k rows from table A and INSERT to table B.

I do this operation in a stored procedure (because I need to do a bunch of other tasks):

```
INSERT INTO B ("fields")
    SELECT "field" 
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN @TempTable -- this join need for filtering records in table A
```

Table structure

**Table A:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A]
(
    [Field1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Field2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Field3] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Field4] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Field5] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Field6] [int] NULL,
    [Field7] [tinyint] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_A] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Field1] ASC, [Field2] ASC, [Field3] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[A] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_...] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Field2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[...] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[A] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [...] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Field3]) REFERENCES [dbo].[...] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[A] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [...] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Field1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[A] ([Id])
GO
```

**Table B:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B]
(
    [Field1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Field2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Field3] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Field4] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Field5] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Field6] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Field7] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_B] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Field1] ASC, [Field2] ASC, [Field3] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[B] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [...] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Field2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[...] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[B] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [...] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Field3]) REFERENCES [dbo].[...] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[B] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [...] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Field1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[...] ([Id])
GO
```

**Infrastructure**:

- SQL Azure Database (Plan S1 - 20 DTU)
- Also, I use Entity Framework Core for executing this stored procedure

With the configuration that I mentioned, insert operation takes 1:55 min, I tried to run only select without insert it takes only 3-5 sec, so that's mean a problem with inserting.

**Solutions that I have already tried:**

**1.** I have removed all indexes before inserting. that improves performance, takes only 45 sec, but indexes anyway should be created after inserting. Indexes recreation takes ~1 min so we get same ~1:55 min. And 45 sec is still a long time.

**2.** I tried to insert using batches (by 5000), this reduce only to 1:35 min.

**Additional info:**
We can't increase "DTU" significantly because when the application works in  regular mode it does not need more than 80% of this resource (S1 - 20 DTU)

Execution plan (**with indexes**):
[Execution plan with indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYT4j.png)

Wait stats (**with indexes**):
[Wait stats with indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNNeM.png)

Execution plan (**without indexes**):
[Execution plan without indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l66dC.png)

### **Questions**:

I have found some information regarding this problem, and possible solutions:

1. Table Partition for table 'B' and then use "Partition Switching" to move data from NOT partition table 'A' to Partition 'B'
2. In-Memory OLTP. Can this help with this problem? Pros and cons?
3. Or maybe you have your variant, how I can perform in this situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the Query Store Wait Stats, or get the Actual Execution Plan and look at the Wait Stats.  That should tell you what the resource bottleneck is.  The improvement options will depend on _why_ it's slow.  But you can try making the destination table a Clustered Colulnstore Index to minimize IO resources.

Comment: " S1 - 20 DTU" - this is extremely resource constrained. I imagine you will likely be maxing out your IO/LOG levels. In-Memory OLTP requires a much higher SKU

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have attached Execution Plan. I have already looked there and  I did not find anything that I can improve

Comment: @MartinSmith "We can't increase "DTU" significantly because when the application works in regular mode it does not need more than 80% of this resource (S1 - 20 DTU)" Actually we have 50 DTU on production but I tried this with 20 DTU but with a lower amount of data of course

Comment: What about the wit stats and querytime stats, eg https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/07/sql-2016-sp1-shows-wait-stats-execution-plans/? and you can share the plan at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Have you considered the alternative, first duplicate table A, then delete just ~50k rows, then insert just 12k rows from table B, finally drop table B and rename.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have added "Wait stats" but I can't share execution plan (XML) because of possible security issues

Comment: @Stu I have thought about this. but we have much more data on "production" so that will cost a lot

Comment: Where are the wait stats?

Comment: @DK_ ok, just an idea based on the info you provided; its usually best to minimise logged operations in favor of a bit of fiddling.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft sorry. now should be there

Comment: Have you tried a `TABLOCK` hint on both tables, that may reduce latch contention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query runtime appears to be dominated by IO waits.

Here are the wait stats

[image]

PAGEIOLATCH_EX is a wait to write to disk, PAGEIOLATCH_SH is a wait to read from disk, and [LOG_RATE_GOVERNOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-logical-server#transaction-log-rate-governance) is essentially also an IO wait, waiting to write to the log file.  The IO and Log write limits on a 20DTU database are quite small, and the standard tier DTU model provisions only [1-4 IOPS/DTU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tiers-dtu#compare-the-dtu-based-service-tiers), so that's under 100 IOPS.

So you can either

1. **Write less data**

-by eliminating columns, especially the `nvarchar(max)` column if it's large

-by compressing the data using Page Compression or a Clustered Columnstore index, or by using the COMPRESS TSQL function for the `nvarchar(max)` column if it is large

or

2. **Provide more resources**

-by scaling to a higher DTU, or VCore configuration, or a Serverless configuration with elastic scale

-by moving to Hyperscale which provides 100MB/S log throughput at every service level

-Moving this database into an Elastic Pool where it can share a larger pool of resources with other databases.

Table partioning won't reduce the amount of writes.  And In-Memory OLTP is only available in the Premium/Business Critical Tier, which already has higher IOPS.